# Exchange Server 2019 ECP Login Issue

Tags: ssl, exchange-server, exchange-server-2019

For a couple of days now, with a huge amount of googling, I have been trying to fix an error on our Exchange 2019 Test server.  Yes I know a reinstall would fix it but I would really like to learn how to fix it without taking the nuclear option!

on the server itself, as well as from a client, we can no longer log into ECP.  We get the login screen, but it crashes when we submit the login details.  I have recreated virtual directories and the self signed exchange certificates.  OWA is also affected.  Email clients like outlook still connect over POP3, IMAP and SMTP so the problem is restricted to web access only.  Below is the relevant event log entry which says it is a certificate problem, but as I said the old one has been removed and recreated.

**Event code: 3005
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred.
Event time: 18/11/2022 16:04:11
Event time (UTC): 18/11/2022 16:04:11
Event ID: befa1cda5aa044f2bca36109c250bf04
Event sequence: 2
Event occurrence: 1
Event detail code: 0

Application information:
Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/ecp-2-133132606657929239
Trust level: Full
Application Virtual Path: /ecp
Application Path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\FrontEnd\HttpProxy\ecp\
Machine name: MAIL

Process information:
Process ID: 11132
Process name: w3wp.exe
Account name: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM

Exception information:
Exception type: HttpException
Exception message: https://localhost/owa/auth/errorFE.aspx?CafeError=SSLCertificateProblem
at Microsoft.Exchange.HttpProxy.FbaModule.OnBeginRequestInternal(HttpApplication httpApplication)
at Microsoft.Exchange.HttpProxy.ProxyModule.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.b__0()
at Microsoft.Exchange.Common.IL.ILUtil.DoTryFilterCatch(Action tryDelegate, Func`2 filterDelegate, Action`1 catchDelegate)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Request information:
Request URL: https://localhost:443/ecp/?ExchClientVer=15
Request path: /ecp/
User host address: ::1
User:
Is authenticated: False
Authentication Type:
Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM

Thread information:
Thread ID: 19
Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
Is impersonating: False
Stack trace:    at Microsoft.Exchange.HttpProxy.FbaModule.OnBeginRequestInternal(HttpApplication httpApplication)
at Microsoft.Exchange.HttpProxy.ProxyModule.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.b__0()
at Microsoft.Exchange.Common.IL.ILUtil.DoTryFilterCatch(Action tryDelegate, Func`2 filterDelegate, Action`1 catchDelegate)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)**